# How to switch the icon on a button when collapsing with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this button

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i>Details</button>
```

And when I click on it I would like to switch for

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"><i class="icon-resize-small"></i>Details</button>
```

and get it back with `icon-fullscreen` when collapsing.

Is there an AngularJS way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this might do the trick:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
  <i ng-class="{'icon-resize-small': isCollapsed, 'icon-fullscreen': !isCollapsed}"></i>Details
</button>
```

In this case, your `i` would have the class `icon-resize-small` when `isCollapsed` is true, and `icon-fullscreen` when it's not true. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).

When passing an object of key-value pairs to ngClass, the keys represent classes which will be applied if their values evaluate to true.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <button ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed">
        <span   ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': isCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !isCollapsed }"></span>
      </button>
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: * EXPLANATION IN COMMENTS * There are many ways you would need to do this and depending on where you are using this feature, I have listed four possible ways where you would be using it. If you are doing this within a directive, then the code would look different as shown below. if you wanna add some function included with the icon change, then I have listed in my comments some scenarios.  For me when I was doing this, I need  a function to expand the panel and that's where I have "somefunction()". Like I said based on your need, here is some scenarios.

Comment: Comments are transitory, and are not included in search results, so it really is best to [edit] the answer to add that info. (It would be a good answer with that stuff, btw!)